# Using media query inside a CSS in the "@media" expression

Tags: html, css, media, mpdf

I read in manual that is possible to use CSS media query like:

```
<link href="mypdf.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="mpdf" />
```

but I need to use it inside a unique CSS stylesheet, using media query. Actually, `@media screen` and `@media print` are working, but seems that mpdf is ignoring `@media mpdf`. I didn't find any example including this tag, so maybe I'm wrong and media query doesn't work that way in mPDF.

```
@media print { dl {  page-break-inside: avoid;  }    }
@media mpdf  { dl {  page-break-inside:inherit;     }    }
```

Moreover, we need to do this cause mPDF is duplicating content inside DL tags when using "`page-break-inside: avoid;`".

Please, any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: There is no such media query to target mpdf only - it is third party plugin and as such not a web standard

Comment: Well, in fact that's the target. Only mPDF processor should interpret this CSS, as you can read here https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/pdf-from-every-page-of-website.html
However, I need to do the same but inside an unique CSS file, and "@media mpdf" is being ignored .... so that's why asked about here.

Comment: So just link a new external stylesheet for your mpdf overrides and don't try to create a non-standard @media query

Comment: I must say mPDF is not a plugin, it's a PHP package that doesn't work with simultaneous media stylesheets. It need an UNIQUE block for CSS, so if I try to use various stylesheets, they must be appended to only one, so that's the need to use @media query.

Comment: As you've said it's external software that uses non standard techniques so either follow their techniques or write something yourself to parse the media queries you want, don't just expect it to work because you want it to

Comment: Well, I asked here looking for an expert in mpdf cause there are not enough documentation about media query in their site and I was doubting if I was missing some information and about if what I asked were possible. You answered me from a CSS/HTML expert point of view, but not really the knowledge I was looking for. So thanks anyway for your comments.

Comment: Does mPDF supports these page-break-inside tags in the way you like? The CSS support is limited (https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) You could test with some simpler CSS whether the @media query is working.

Comment: Thank you Klap-in. I read that page before posting here, but as for sure you noticed, in that page doesn't seems page-break-inside were not supported by mPDF. The worst thing is that doesn't mention @media tag anywhere, so I finished here cause a mPDF member told me to ask here, instead of answer my question in github.com. Anyway, I take my time to try as you proposed, with a simpler CSS and making a "trial and error", I have no choices  ;)

Comment: After reading a lot more and driving me crazy about media query support in mPDF, I found this thread in their own forum at github ...
https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/758
That say it all. Documentation is not clear at this respect, so even who answered and closed at first time the issue doesn't know exactly how it works!!  :(

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you need to set the configuration variable CSSselectMedia to your media query name 'mpdf'.

```php
// require composer autoload
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->CSSselectMedia = 'mpdf';
...
```

for more detail: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/cssselectmedia.html

The example from https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/pdf-from-every-page-of-website.html is using it too.

Comment: Thank you!!! Very complete info and links. I'll try your recommendation (can't vote cause my reputation is <15)  , sorry